# Одинаковая x y z ориентация анимация при повернутого (например, на 180 градусов) симметричного объекта. Глобальная ориентация анимации

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация, разработка-игр

Есть куб в юнити со своей анимацией, как сделать так, чтобы при повороте на 90, 180 градусов. анимация воспроизводилась так, как будто куб не поворачивали (т.к анимация воспроизводится боком, если куб падает, например, на бок)? Т.е как бы сделать анимацию ориентированную на глобальные оси x,y,z а не на внутренние. Пока только была мысль что это можно реализовать через массив vertices, но чет замудрено получается, мне кажется это делается проще.

Comment: Анимируй пустой гейобжект и прицепи на него этот куб под любым поворотом.

Comment: Ты наверно не так понял. Так и делал изначально, у меня куб является дочерним элементов пустого геймобджекта с ригидбоди, но не работает, то есть объект движется по игровому миру и анимируется, но если он падает на бок, анимация (например, подпрыгивания (именно анимация, а не эдфорс и т.д) проигрывается уже вбок.

Comment: Ну так отсоедини куб, обнули поворот, скейл у пустышки и подсоедини обратно.

Comment: А как это сделать в коде? Если куб падает на бок вследствии игровой физики во время игрового процесса, а не моих манипуляций.

Comment: `box.transform.parent = null;`  `box.transform.parent = animGo.transform`